# Working with Resources and User-defined Control Properties

Tags: c#, winforms, coding-style, methods

I am creating a custom control and it is a button. It may has a type and a specified image according to its type. Its type may be:

```
public enum ButtonType
{
    PAUSE,
    PLAY
}
```

Now I can change its appearance and Image with a method:

```
public ButtonType buttonType;
public void ChangeButtonType(ButtonType type)
{
    // change button image
    if (type == ButtonType.PAUSE)
        button1.Image = CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PauseButton;
    else if (type == ButtonType.PLAY)
        button1.Image = CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PlayButton;

    buttonType = type;
}
```

OK, this method doesn't seems so good, for example maybe later I wish to have another type `STOP` for example for this button, I want just add its image to resources and add it to `ButtonType` enum, without changing this method.

**How can I implement this method to be compatible with future changes?**

Comment: Where is the `ChangeButtonType` method? Is it on your custom button?

Comment: @Anna: yes it is, it is a control library and this method and that enum and all are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is turn `ButtonType` into a base class (or an interface, if you prefer):

```
public abstract class ButtonType
{
    public abstract Image GetImage();
}
```

Then each of your types becomes a subclass:

```
public class PauseButtonType : ButtonType
{
    public Image GetImage()
    {
        return CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PauseButton;
    }
}

public class PlayButtonType : ButtonType
{
    public Image GetImage()
    {
        return CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PlayButton;
    }
}
```

Your image changing method then becomes:

```
private ButtonType buttonType; // public variables usually aren't a good idea
public void ChangeButtonType(ButtonType type)
{
    button1.Image = type.GetImage();
    buttonType = type;
}
```

This way when you want to add another type, you add another ButtonType subclass and pass it to your `ChangeButtonType` method.

---

Since this method is on your custom button class, I would probably take this a bit further and encapsulate style/appearance in a class:

```
public class ButtonStyle
{
    // might have other, non-abstract properties like standard width, height, color
    public abstract Image GetImage();
}

// similar subclasses to above
```

And then on the button itself:

```
public void SetStyle(ButtonStyle style)
{
    this.Image = style.GetImage();
    // other properties, if needed
}
```

You could set up button behaviours (i.e. actions they perform when they're clicked) in a similar way with a ButtonAction base class and assigning specific actions like Stop and Play when you want to change the button's purpose and style.

Answer (score 2):

Don`t know if this is the best option, but you can create a custom property to your enum, containing the image

```
public enum ButtonType
{
    [ButtonImage(CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PauseButton)]
    PAUSE,

    [ButtonImage(CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PlayButton)]
    PLAY
}
```

I won't go into detail about this, as this is easy to google for... In fact, this is a good resource to start:

http://joelforman.blogspot.com/2007/12/enums-and-custom-attributes.html?showComment=1317161231873#c262630108634229289